# Total Trigger Time in appsript

Tags: google-apps-script

The Google article suggests that total trigger time is 6 hours per day. However it does not give any hint about how it is applied. this quota limit is per user or per script?

Comment: Please add a link to the google-article. Thanks!

Comment: link to google article : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Answer (score 0):

The Total Trigger time which is 6 hours per day is per user which suggests that a user account which all the scripts included have total running time of 360 minutes per day. it is not per script.